# How to have different controllers/actions for one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

What is the best method to have one single view (I have one html page with different sections () sort of like mini pages on one page) and have different sections call different controllers and actions through that one view?
Because in layouts only one <%= yield %> is acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider to use [partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials), where each partial is allocated to one controller. Within an erb or haml-template, you could call these partials. e.g.:

```
<div id="content">
  <%= render "content/articles" %>
  <%= render "news/list" %>
</div>
```

Comment: how do I allocate that particular partial to a particular controller?

Comment: well, my wording did not match exactly to the rails slang. but: if you have generated a "news"-controller with the controller named `controllers/news_controller.rb` and a views folder at `views/news`, then you could put a partial called `_list.html.erb` into this views folder. if i did understand your question right, this would be a simple approach. to understand more, you should read some basic stuff about how rails works, e.g. about [rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html),  [generators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate).

Answer (score 0):

You can have partials for the different sections of your view but I don't see how you would get different controllers/actions for one single request, nor why it would make sense to do that except if your different sections can be refreshed independently on client side via ajax, in which case you could have different controllers/actions that render the different partials.